# Is there an annotation for data transformations in DTOs?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to create a .NET Core REST API acting as a proxy between two systems. The receiving system takes in specific values but the sending system sends values in different variations.

Given the following example that the receiving system expects the following gender keys of type `string`

- male
- female
- diverse
- undefined

The sending system may send variations for "male" e.g. "m". If the value in the DTO is "m" I want to transform it to "male". If the key atches nowhere, it should simply send back a 400. I know that I can create validation attributes but can I also create transform attributes?

Maybe I can directly transform the DTO value in the attribute?

This is my current example showing what I want to achieve

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class MyValidationAttribute : System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            string key = value.ToString();

            switch (key)
            {
                case "male":
                case "m":
                    key = "male"; // Transform the value from the DTO here
                    break;
                case "female":
                case "f":
                    key = "female"; // ...
                    break;
                
                // ...

                default:
                    return false; // Throw 400 because the value didn't match
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name) => "... Invalid ...";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom converter for your field in the DTO. Assuming you have some kind of gender enumeration in your code, you could introduce the custom attribute to enlist the possible values for your enumeration value. Such as `DescriptionsAttribute`:

```
using System;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class DescriptionsAttribute : Attribute
{
    public DescriptionsAttribute(params string[] values)
    {
        Values = values ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(values));
    }

    public string[] Values { get; }
}
```

This attribute implementation will allow you to add one to many descriptions per value within your enumeration. You could then use this custom attribute to describe the fields within your `Gender` enumeration. I've left the `Undefined` value without any description on purpose because I'm planning to use it as a fallback value later on, but you can change it according to your needs.

```
public enum Gender
{
    [Descriptions("m", "male")]
    Male,

    [Descriptions("f", "female")]
    Female,

    [Descriptions("d", "diverse")]
    Diverse,

    Undefined
}
```

What you also need is some way to extract the `DescriptionsAttribute` values from the enumeration fields. I've encapsulated that logic within an extension method.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static T GetAttribute<T>(this Enum value) where T : Attribute
    {
        string stringValue = value.ToString();

        MemberInfo memberInfo = value
            .GetType()
            .GetMember(stringValue)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        return memberInfo?
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false)
            .Cast<T>()
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Once you've done that, you can provide the custom `JsonConverter<Gender>` implementation. In the following example, I'm allowing the case insensitive `Gender` matching and having `Undefined` as a fallback value for all the cases when there is no appropriate match.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public class GenderConverter : JsonConverter<Gender>
{
    public override Gender Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        string value = reader.GetString();

        foreach (Gender gender in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender)))
        {
            string[] descriptions = gender.GetAttribute<DescriptionsAttribute>()?.Values;

            if (descriptions != null &&
                descriptions.Any(description => description.Equals(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
            {
                return gender;
            }
        }

        return Gender.Undefined;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Gender value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Finally, you would then just need to decorate your `Gender` property within your DTO with an appropriate `JsonConverter` implementation usage.

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public class SomeDto
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(GenderConverter))]
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: ok this is really a massive overkill but yeah thanks :D